# Socket can't connect to ServerSocket outside a local network, even though the specified ports have been opened

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

In my recent addition to the software engine I am working on, there seems to be a major issue.

Whenever I try to use the networking features with a client, or server, outside my local network, it fails to connect. While inside my local network, it works flawlessly, without even a hint of failiure. I tried to forward the ports, but with no success. There should be no problem with the server code, nor the client code, since it works inside my network. I have even made sure that the server binds to my local network address, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I am able to host, and connect to servers, using other Java application, which makes this an odd exception. Do I have to configure my firewall, again, or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Setup port-forwarding to bypass your local (or potentially the remote) network firewall. If it works on a local network, then it is probably a firewall issue between your local system and the remote system.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming related question, but one related to networking in general and/or routing, firewalling, NAT-traversing in particular.